# How to export 4D single variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

Trying to export " 4D data " in matlab. 
when I export this variable to a text file as :

```
save ('file.txt','var')
```

I get following output:

error

or

```
save('file.txt', 'var', '-ascii' )

Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
```

Comment: What kind of text format are you expecting? Human-readable or should it be processed by some other program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. Matlab is unable to save multi-dimensional variables in ASCII format. Also, Matlab only saves up to 8 digits by default and since your data is of single precision so you may loose some precision.

The solution:

1. do not save it as ASCII. Instead, use `-mat` (Matlab binary format);
2. reshape your variable into a 2D matrix for writing but make sure you know its original size so you can reshape it back into a 4D matrix when reading;
3. use `fprintf` to create your own function that saves 4D matrices to a text file;
4. use something else than Matlab. If you're really stuck with something with Matlab-like syntax, Octave has a `-text` format which allows saving of N dimensional matrices to a text file.

Comment: @user1426913 that doesn't make any sense, a simple text file is only 2 dimensions. How would you represent more dimensions? A binary file format seems to be your best shot but if you're stuck with Matlab, you will have to find a library capable of reading mat files. Alternatively, you can also try to save them as hdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Using `save` command saves the variable using a binary format used by Matlab. If you want your variable to be saved in a text format use the `'-ascii'` flag for the `save` command:

```
save('file.txt', 'var', '-ascii' );
```

see [documentation of `save` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) for more information.

Comment: @user1426913 it seems like `'-ascii'` flags does not support saving arrays with more than two dimensions. You'll have to either `reshape` your variable before saving or save it in a binary format.